# PostgreSQL remote connection failing

Tags: postgresql, configuration, connectivity, postgresql-12

I've recently installed PostgreSQL on my PC as a requirement for my DB class, and as a practice, I decided to try and setup a remote connection for it so I can access it via online services. But after hours of searching the internet and dba.stackexchange and trying different configurations, I still can't get it to work. Here are some of the things I've tried:

- Added `listen_addresses = '*'` in the `postgresql.conf` file
- Added the following lines to the `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# Allowing IPv4 remote connections
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 scram-sha-256

# Allowing IPv6 remote connections
host all all ::/0 scram-sha-256
```

- Restarted the service via the `pg_ctl restart` command. The logged outputs:

```
2021-04-30 09:23:45.821 +0430 [12108] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2021-04-30 09:23:45.825 +0430 [12108] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-04-30 09:23:45.826 +0430 [12108] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-04-30 09:23:45.971 +0430 [7276] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-30 09:23:45 +0430
2021-04-30 09:23:46.037 +0430 [12108] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

- Checked the `pg_ctl status` command's output:

```
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 12108)
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/bin/postgres.exe
```

- And finally when entering my credentials for the web service I am trying to connect from, I made sure to enter the IP that [whatsmyip](https://www.whatsmyip.org/) gave me for the `Hostname` field.

I am all out of ideas on what to do. Is there a step that I am missing? Since I'm a beginner, I may have made a silly beginner's mistake (like entering the wrong username!), though I did check my credentials multiple times and I don't think there's anything wrong with them.

I am running PostgreSQL 13.2 on Windows 10.

The web service I am trying to connect to my local DB is [Deepnote](http://deepnote.com/)'s PostgreSQL integration. Are there any other ways that I can try to see if my configuration works?

I added a new rule in the `Windows Defender Firewall > Inbound Rules` section to allow TCP connections on port 5432.

Then I restarted the server with `pg_ctl restart` and ran the command `netstat -a | sls 5432` (PowerShell) which returned the following output:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           MyPCName:0        LISTENING
TCP    [::]:5432              MyPCName:0        LISTENING
```

But I still get the error message:

```
Could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "MyIPAddress" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is the exact error I get, as requested in the comments.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I got the logs and added them in the edit of my question as you asked.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a firewall issue, if you gor the server address and port right.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I disabled the entire system's firewall and still receive the same error message. I am all out of ideas on what to do. Doesn't `netstat`'s output indicate that everything should be working?

Comment: Just because you disabled your local machine's firewall doesn't mean there is not another one between you and internet.  The fact that you used whatsmyip kind of suggests that you are behind a NAT.

Comment: @jjanes I ran `ipconfig` and the results returned a 192.168 sort of IP. I guess you're right and I should try to find a solution to bypass the router firewall.